# error while installing pyserial on beaglebone black with angstrom

Tags: pyserial, beagleboneblack, angstrom-linux

I entered the following command to install pyserial on my beaglebone black - rev C with angstrom OS:

```
pip install pyserial
```

and I got the following error msgs:

```
Downloading/unpacking pyserial
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pyserial
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-root/pyserial/setup.py", line 23, in <module>
        import serial
      File "serial/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
        import importlib
    ImportError: No module named importlib
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>

  File "/tmp/pip-build-root/pyserial/setup.py", line 23, in <module>

    import serial

  File "serial/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>

    import importlib

ImportError: No module named importlib

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-root/pyserial
Storing complete log in /home/root/.pip/pip.log
```

Please how can I fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Use the official Debian image from http://beagleboard.org/latest-images - the old Angstrom image has a broken Python build and hasn't been supported by BeagleBoard.org for a few years now.